# Retrofit 2.0 method without response

Tags: android, retrofit

In my current android project I'm sending some data to my web server with the new Retrofit 2.0 library. I only want to run a script there and the server does not return anything. I thought I can do this with this method:

```
@POST("persons/insert.php")
Call<Void> insert(@Field("Name") String name);
```

My problem now is, that Retrofit jumps to the `onFailure` method although the server returns 200. That happens because nothing can be converted to `Void`. So how should I fix this method? I want that the `onResponse` method is called if the server sends 200 back and the `onFailure` if an error occurred. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can have it return a `ResponseBody`.

```
@POST("persons/insert.php")
Call<ResponseBody> insert(@Field("Name") String name);
```

You will still get `onResponse` and `onFailure`, but it will not try to deserialize the stream to an object.

Answer (score 7):

You can completely avoid the response body. 
In beta2, you can do `Call<Void>` to discard the response body and just obtain the http status code.

```
@POST("persons/insert.php")
Call<Void> insert(@Field("Name") String name);
```